# Why is the extended method not over-riding the parent method

Tags: php, class

I need to be able to run a child method from the parent class.
I am calling the child function $this->getPlan, but it is not calling the child plan, but only the parent one. I thought an extended class over-rides the function.
Here is my code

```
class logon{
    public function getPlan(){}
    public function __construct(){
    }
    public function checkWorks(){
        $this->getPlan();       
    }
}

class plan extends logon{       
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function getPlan(){
        echo "test";    
    }
}
$logon = new logon();
$plan = new plan();

$logon->checkWorks();
```

However if I call the code from the parent constructor like this, it calls my child method.

```
public function __construct(){
      $this->getPlan();
    }
```

I don't want to use an abstract class to do this, as there is a good reason for this.
Can anyone tell me why my parent method is not being over-ridden by the child class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem a different way.
The initial problem was this. I needed to include logon class in plan so that I could access the database. The problem was that logon needed to run a method in plan, and I couldn't include the plan class as that would have created a cyclic problem.

My solution was halfway there, but I have a proper solution. By making the plan class a child solved the problem of not including logon to access the database, but I still could call a method in plan. Now I am not including logon in plan I can include plan in logon which has solved the problem, and it works. Here is my solution. Now I can access my method from both classes. I knew I would find a way if I just tried hard enough.

```
class logon{
    public function __construct(){
    }
    public function checkWorks(){
        $p= new plan();
        $p->getPlan();
    }
}

class plan extends logon{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function getPlan(){
        echo "test";    
    }
}

$logon = new logon();
$logon->checkWorks();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling logon method:

```
$logon->checkWorks();
```

but `getPlan` in `logon` class is empty. You need to call child class (Plan):

```
$plan->checkWorks();
```

Comment: I know I can do it that way, but I need to call the method from my logon class. Basically I need the method to work in both classess. You see when I login my logon class is run. I need to call a method in my child class from my main class, as it does certain checks.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams - so define getPlan in your logon class. Your code above won't work, it's not possible this way.

Comment: I realise I can do that, but the plan class has all the methods needed for the plan. Whereas logon has all the methods for the logon. So I didn't want to put duplicate methods in both classes. My plan class uses certain methods from the logon class. My logon class only needs to call one method from the plan class.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams - you don't need to put redundant code in both classes. Define getPlan only in logon class. Or better, refactor your code. Your app logic isn't probably very good.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams - you should either add real code or delete your question (or maybe approve my answer). Because you get your answer and there is no reason why you can't use `$plan->checkWorks();`. Maybe if you add your real code, we could answer your question.

Comment: I can't add my real code, as some of it is private, and it would be very long to post here. The logon class is included in many other classes, because it has the main connection function, as well as other functions needed for the user. The plan class has all the plan methods. I didn't want to put plan methods in the logon class as i wanted to keep them separate. So that I can call them directly from the plan class. However there is one method I need to call in my plan class that is needed to be called from my logon class, so now I am a little stuck.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams - as I said, your application logic isn't good. Plan shouldn't be extending logon. And if you don't want to add real code I am voting to close this question.

Comment: I only extended logon because I wanted both classes to access the same method. I originally didn't extend and included logon in my plan class. The problem is that I couldn't call my plan method in my logon class and thought extending would solve the problem. I am not allowed to post company code on this site and the code I posted shows the problem, so why ask for real code? logon has all the connect code for mysql, and without that the plan class cannot access mysql. If I include the logon in my class I can't do it the other way around because that would cause a cyclic error.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams like I said before - put getPlan logic inside logon class. Why you wouldn't do that way?